# How to get value of same nodes in XML in c#

Tags: c#, xml

## I want to get the value of artist (Bob Dylan) for title "Greatest Hits" in the xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <price>10.0</price>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adapt it as you need ...

```
using System.Xml;

static void GetArtistFromXml()
{
    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO - 8859 - 1\"?><catalog><cd><title>Empire Burlesque</title><artist>Bob Dylan</artist><price>10.90</price></cd><cd><title>Hide your heart</title><artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist><price>10.0</price></cd><cd><title>Greatest Hits</title><artist>Bob Dylan</artist><price>10.90</price></cd></catalog>";

    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

    var artistElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//cd[title[text()=\"Greatest Hits\"]]/artist");

    Console.WriteLine(artistElement.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filename = @"e:\Temp\AmeyP.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

    string artist = xdoc.Descendants("cd")
        .Where(x => x.Element("title").Value.Equals("Greatest Hits"))
        .Elements("artist").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(artist);
}
```

**Output**

**Bob Dylan**

Comment: How/why is it better?

Comment: Because it is simpler, and more functionality.